# how to make apply/call/bind work here?

Tags: javascript

i need a hand on getting this to work.
Thought i understand 'this' but it has been quite a pain.

If i run this code, the first console.log works as expected. It logs out: 'bob red,blue' , with `this.name` refering tot 'bob'.

the second console.log does something weird, it logs out 'result red' and 'result blue' - with `this.name` referring to 'result'.
I don't know where it get's 'result' from but that's not my main question.

I know i can make a `var that = this` to refer to 'bob' with that.name.
My main question is: how would you make this.name inside the second console.log refer to 'bob' using apply/call or bind?

```js
const person = {
  name: 'bob',
  cars: ['red', 'blue'],
  output: function() {
    console.log(this.name + ' ' + this.cars);
    this.cars.forEach(function(car) {
      console.log(`${this.name} ${car}`)
    })
  }
}

person.output()
```

Comment: An even simpler way would be to make your `forEach` function an arrow function: http://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/#ecmascript-2015-features-arrows-and-lexical-this

Comment: @taylorc93, i know about arrow functions using lexical scope as this, but i'm curious how to do it with call/apply or bind. T

Comment: Also look at the second, optional, argument for `forEach`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's 3 ways I would suggest doing this. First, an arrow function (if your environments support it):

```js
const person = {
  name: 'bob',
  cars: ['red', 'blue'],
  output: function() {
    console.log(this.name + ' ' + this.cars);
    this.cars.forEach((car) => { // <--
      console.log(`${this.name} ${car}`);
    });
  }
}

person.output();
```

Next, would be to use a feature of `forEach` itself and pass `this` as the last argument:

```js
const person = {
  name: 'bob',
  cars: ['red', 'blue'],
  output: function() {
    console.log(this.name + ' ' + this.cars);
    this.cars.forEach(function(car) {
      console.log(`${this.name} ${car}`);
    }, this); // <--
  }
}

person.output();
```

Finally, you could use `bind` like so:

```js
const person = {
  name: 'bob',
  cars: ['red', 'blue'],
  output: function() {
    console.log(this.name + ' ' + this.cars);
    this.cars.forEach(function(car) {
      console.log(`${this.name} ${car}`);
    }.bind(this)); // <--
  }
}

person.output();
```

Theoretically, you could use `apply` or `call` but it's more hassle:

```js
const person = {
  name: 'bob',
  cars: ['red', 'blue'],
  output: function() {
    console.log(this.name + ' ' + this.cars);
    function printCar(car) {
      console.log(`${this.name} ${car}`);
    }
    
    const self = this;
    this.cars.forEach(function(car) {
      printCar.call(self, car);
    });
  }
}

person.output();
```

```js
const person = {
  name: 'bob',
  cars: ['red', 'blue'],
  output: function() {
    console.log(this.name + ' ' + this.cars);
    function printCar(car) {
      console.log(`${this.name} ${car}`);
    }
    
    const self = this;
    this.cars.forEach(function(car) {
      printCar.apply(self, [car]);
    });
  }
}

person.output();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript you'll need to cache `this`, otherwise it will lose its context. With arrow functions it would have worked (replacing `function` with `=>`), but that's another story.

Updated example:

```js
const person = {
  name: 'bob',
  cars: ['red', 'blue'],
  output: function() {
    var that = this;
    console.log(this.name + ' ' + this.cars);
    this.cars.forEach(function(car) {
      console.log(`${that.name} ${car}`)
    })
  }
}

person.output()
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I skipped reading the last bit of your question. Well, this works, but it doesn't answer your Q really ;)

Answer (score 1):

These are all combinations I can think of at the moment. I also added arrow functions (which do not have a lexical environment) and the usage of the this argument of forEach.

```js
const person = {
 name: 'bob',
  cars: ['red', 'blue'],
  output: function() {
   console.log(this.name + ' ' + this.cars);
    
    console.info("Arrow function");
    
    this.cars.forEach((car) => {
     console.log(`${this.name} ${car}`)
    });
    
    console.info("thisArg of forEach");
    
    this.cars.forEach(function (car) {
     console.log(`${this.name} ${car}`)
    }, this);
    
    console.info(".bind()");
    
    this.cars.forEach(function (car) {
     console.log(`${this.name} ${car}`)
    }.bind(this));
    
    console.info(".call()");
    
    (function (cars) {
      for (let c of cars) {
       console.log(`${this.name} ${c}`)
      }
    }).call(this, this.cars);   
    
    console.info(".apply()");
    
    (function (...cars) {
      for (let c of cars) {
       console.log(`${this.name} ${c}`)
      }
    }).apply(this, this.cars);   
  }
}

person.output()
```